# angular array loop and sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops, sorting

I have an array of objects, each object contains the following properties:

```
comments:""
id:1
inProgress:false
jobDescription:null
lastUpdateDate:"07/08/2016"
lastUpdatedByUser:"xxx@abc.com"
product:"Chicken"
status:Object
templateName:"Standard Template"
uploadDate:"07/08/2016 10:36:01"
```

I need a function in angular that I can loop through the entire list and sort through the uploadDate and have the most recent first, etc.

I tried using this but it did not work:

```
vm.uploads = $filter('orderBy')(vm.uploads, vm.uploads[0].uploadDate, reverse);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### [Array.prototype.sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) is enough :

```
vm.uploads.sort(function(a,b){
   return  new Date(a.uploadDate).getTime()- new Date(b.uploadDate).getTime();
})
```

If you want `desc` order , just switch `a` & `b`

Answer (score 1):

Your have a *syntax* error, you should call it like this:

```
vm.uploads = $filter('orderBy')(vm.uploads, 'uploadDate', true)
```

Take a look on this simple **demo**:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  function MainCtrl($filter) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.reverse = false;
    vm.uploads = [  
       {  
          "comments":"",
          "id":1,
          "inProgress":false,
          "jobDescription":null,
          "lastUpdateDate":"07/08/2016",
          "lastUpdatedByUser":"xxx@abc.com",
          "product":"Chicken",
          "status":1,
          "templateName":"Standard Template",
          "uploadDate":"07/08/2016 10:36:01"
       },
       {  
          "comments":"",
          "id":2,
          "inProgress":true,
          "jobDescription":null,
          "lastUpdateDate":"08/08/2016",
          "lastUpdatedByUser":"xxx@abc.com",
          "product":"Horse",
          "status":1,
          "templateName":"Custom Template",
          "uploadDate":"08/08/2016 12:49:05"
       }
    ];

    vm.order = function () {
      vm.uploads = $filter('orderBy')(vm.uploads, 'uploadDate', vm.reverse = !vm.reverse);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="upload in main.uploads track by $index" ng-bind="upload.uploadDate"></li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <button type="button" value="order" ng-click="main.order()">Change order</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I'd recommend you to check the [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).